# How to create JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json

I need to create JSON like this:

```json
{
  "files": [
    {
      "file_path": "example.txt",
      "content" : "source code \n with multiple lines\n"
    }
  ]
}
```

But my code (I serialized it to JSON later) doesn't correspond to this example above

```cs
var requestBody = new
{
    files = new string[] { snippet.FileName, snippet.Content }
};
```

Can someone help me :)?

EDIT:

my serialization method:

```
        protected string serializeToJson( object obj )
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject( obj, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() } );
        }
```

Comment: Where's the code that does the de/serialization?

Comment: You don't have an array of string, you have an array of something that has two string properties - file_path and content

Comment: @Enigmativity i put it in my question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Try That:**

```
using System.Text.Json;

var obj = new
{
    files = new[]
    {
        new
        {
            file_path = "example.txt", 
            content ="source code \n with multiple lines\n" 
        }
    }
};
var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: work perfect for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of the serializeobject to convert into json

```
string jsonStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

This method will be available in the newtonsoft package